# Storing the result of a test in a variable

Tags: c#

I am new to C# (and programming in general) so I am unsure how to ask this using proper terms (please bear with me):

What I am trying to do is, if a set of conditions are true, I want to create a new value that is true (so it equals 1). A new set of conditions later in the code will contain the new value as a variable (along with a number of other new conditions). Basically it will look like this:

```
// Condition set 1
if (Position.GetProfitLoss(Close[0], PerformanceUnit.Percent) < -0.015)
{
   //this section will have a newly created value ('variable1') 
   //that if true will equal 1, and if false will equal 0
}
```

in the next condition set, the previously created variable will be a part of the decision:

```
// Condition set 2
if (RVI>50)
&& variable1=1
{
   Buy100Shares
}
```

How do I define the first variable?

Comment: If you're a beginning programmer, I hope this "automated trading" is for play money. There are so many ways to mess up automated trading algorithms, and the consequences when dealing with real money can be rather severe.

Comment: This question is is asking a specific coding question and providing example code. I don't understand why it is being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You define the first variable as a boolean. C# offers you the `bool` type:

```
bool meetsThreshold = (Position.GetProfitLoss(Close[0], PerformanceUnit.Percent) < -0.015);
```

After this line of code has executed, `meetsThreshold` will either be `true` or `false`.

You can then use this variable in later predicates:

```
if ((RVI>50) && meetsThreshold)
{
   Buy100Shares
}
```